# Placement of original author and editor are swapped compared to web

Tags: bug, ios-app

In browsers the author of a question is to the far right at the bottom and anyone who has edited the question is shown to the left of that. In the app those two have swapped places, creating unnecessary opportunities for confusion due to habit.

- App Version: 1.6.2.5
- Device: iPhone 5 (Global)
- OS Version: Version 10.2 (Build 14C92)